# Is there a GENERIC (windows) program to do CRUD for a database table

Tags: windows, database

I am looking for a generic input frontend to perform simple CRUD in a database, either MySQL or SQLite. Ideally I should be able to read the table specification (`describe XYZ`) and the program would automatically create input boxes for this table, possibly with restrictions for length and different types.

It it assumed that the tables are fairly simple and no releation checks need to be done.

I am not looking for a PHP / Java / or other web solution. Should be a windows software.

If it exists, I can spare myself creating it.

Edit: needed software could read creation and make a GUI with input fields:

```
Field       Type         
----------  -----------  
test        varchar(80)  <<< normal text input, limit 80
field2      varchar(80)  <<< normal text input, limit 80
somedate    datetime     <<< date selector
yesnofield  tinyint(1)   <<< checkbox
```

Comment: The Form Builder of MS Access + ODBC   (alternatively, Visual Basic + ODBC) used to be way to do this on Windows. Countless solutions based on this platform existed in the 90s. I think it still viable today, although Microsoft has been neglecting these technologies  since 2010 or so.

Comment: Navicat Premium is a good Windows GUI for many type of databases: https://www.navicat.com

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains DataGrip https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/ is (for me personally) a ver good database editor also for basic CRUD operations. I use it personally in my daily workflow if I working with databases.